# Why 90 degree rotation form a special case in Euler angle representation of rotation

Tags: matrices, trigonometry, rotations

I was reading a document illustrating Euler angles representation of rotations. A Rotation that depends on 3 angles $\alpha$ around z axis, $\beta$ around y axis, and $\gamma$ around x axis is described as follows:

[image: rotation]

The author tried to evaluate a value for the angles given an arbitrary matrix. He first tried to evaluate the value of $\beta$ and stated that:
$\cos^2 (\beta)    = r_{11}^2  + r_{21}^2$ , as long as $\cos (\beta)  \neq{0}$ .

I can't understand the need to impose this constraint on $\beta$ (given my basic knowledge of trigonometry). Is it because $\cos(90^{\circ})$ is zero and zero cannot be common factor?

Also, The author divided the possible values of the other angles $\alpha$ and $\gamma$ depending on whether $\beta$ is equal $\pm{90}$ degrees or not.  Can you please refer to some other resources on this point?

Answer (score 2):

When $\beta=\frac{\pi}{2}$ then the last rotation is parallel to the first rotation. Each successive rotation applies to the local intermediate axes. An orthogonal rotation about *y* rotates the *z* axis into the *x* axis, and the *x* axis onto the -*z* axis. So the subsequent rotation about *x* acts in the same direction as the first rotation about *z*. Hence the rotations *cannot* be decomposed from one another.

Comment: Since each successive rotation applies to the local intermediate axis, any rotation around $y$ will give you a new, intermediate $x$ and $z$ axis.  I don't quite get what you mean by a rotation cannot be decompose from one another.